# How to get id of the button of fileuploadfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

How do I get the id of the button of a fileuploadfield? I tried. Ext.getCmp('idFileupload1').buttonEl.id but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you would ever need it but here is how:

```
Ext.select('.x-form-file-btn button').elements[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Open it in browser and right click -> "Inspect element" in Chrome, it's also the same in firefox,.etc.